# How to pass a empty/null parameter to a report

Tags: vb.net

When passing a filter parameter (null and blank checked) to a report in vb.net, I was thinking if the parameter is blank all records would show. It does not. What is the logic behind optional parameters?

```
Private Sub Form2_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    'TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'SkeduleringDatabasisDataSet.Skedulering' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
    Me.SkeduleringTableAdapter.Fill(Me.SkeduleringDatabasisDataSet.Skedulering)
    Dim param1 As New ReportParameter
    param1.Name = "ReportParameter1"
    param1.Values.Add(Form1.ComboBox1.SelectedValue)

    ReportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportPath = "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Trash\WindowsApplication67\WindowsApplication67\Report1.rdlc"

    ReportViewer1.LocalReport.SetParameters(New ReportParameter() {param1})
    Me.ReportViewer1.RefreshReport()
End Sub
```

So if I do not make a selection in the combobox (`ComboBox1.SelectedIndex` = -1) I am expecting the report to show all data?

Comment: What parameters do you need to give to `ReportViewer1.LocalReport` to show all records? You can test `Form1.ComboBox1.SeletedIndex = -1` to find if no selection has been made.

Comment: Hello Andrew, thank you for your reply. When no selection is made the report returns no records, only the headers. I was expecting it to return all records ? Regards

Comment: If you do not use `ReportViewer1.LocalReport.SetParameters(New ReportParameter() {param1})` does it return all the records?

Comment: Hi Andrew, No it returns only the headers and no records.